# Filtering a textSearch in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Is there a way to filter results of a textsearch in pymongo. I have a cursor:

```
db.models.find(
            {'$text': {'$search': 'some_word'}},
            {'score': {'$meta': 'textScore'}})
```

But this searches whole collection and I want only to search on specific document that have a specific value on some field.

something like this:

```
db.models.find(
                {'$text': {'$search': 'some_word'}},
                {'score': {'$meta': 'textScore'}}
                {'$filter: {'field1': 'some_value'}}) `// this doesn't work`
```

I only want text search to search on documents which have 'some_value' on field1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't search the whole collection. It uses a text index. Text indices match the stemmed terms in the `$search` to terms in the index which indicate exactly which documents contain those terms. It does not scan every document to see which match. You can apply additional conditions to the text match like so:

```
> db.models.find({ "$text" : { "$search" : "some_word" }, "field1" : "some_value" })
```